# RabbitMQ: erl not found

Tags: rabbitmq

When attempting to use `rabbitmqctl`, I get the following error:

```
$ which rabbitmqctl
/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl
$ sudo rabbitmqctl status
/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: line 29: exec: erl: not found
```

(`/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl` most likely invokes `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl` in its source: `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/${SCRIPT}` - guessing `${SCRIPT}` evaluates to `rabbitmqctl`)

However, when simply accessing `erl` from the shell, I reach the erlang shell as expected

```
$ which erl
/usr/local/bin/erl
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/erl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jul 18 02:03 /usr/local/bin/erl -> ../lib/erlang/bin/erl
$ erl
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

Setup information:

- CentOS 6.2
- Erlang R15B01 compiled from `otp_src_R15B01.tar.gz`
- RabbitMQ 2.8.4 installed from `rabbitmq-server-2.8.4-1.noarch.rpm`. Default configuration (no conf files).

Path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myuser/bin
```

---

After looking in the source of `rabbitmqctl`, it seems this is just a simple invocation to `erl`, no magic involved:

```
exec erl \
    -pa "${RABBITMQ_HOME}/ebin" \
    -noinput \
    -hidden \
    ${RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS} \
    -sname rabbitmqctl$$ \
    -s rabbit_control \
    -nodename $RABBITMQ_NODENAME \
    -extra "$@"
```

Can't seem to figure out what the problem really is...

Comment: What's the `PATH` at the time of the exec?

Comment: Added `PATH` info to post via edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As expected, it was a `PATH` problem:

```
$ sudo which erl
which: no erl in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

Resolved this by creating a symlink for `erl`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/erl /usr/bin/erl
```

Maybe a symlink to `/usr/bin` can be avoided somehow (`/usr/local/...` or something).

Comment: Thanks to the guys at #rabbitmq (freenode) for helping me out.

Comment: It looks like you installed Erlang by yourself.  There's actually an Erlang 4.1 rpm in the EPEL repository for CentOS6.  It would likely be better if you used that, unless RabbitMQ had specific version requirements.  In general, you should prefer package installations over compile-it-yourself, unless you have specific reasons not to use the package.

Comment: Actually, you should NEVER prefer package installations over compile it yourself for tools which are core to your business. The upstream versions are always much more up to date, and if they do not distribute an RPM or DEB version, then build it yourself is better. In particular RabbitMQ has made great advances in the last couple of years and all Linux distros have lagged far behind because they don't consider RabbitMQ to be that important.

Comment: I didn't even have erl in `/usr/local/bin`, but found it in `/usr/local/lib/erlang/bin/`